# Build failed with an exception -(app:mergeDebugResources')

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Am running a react native application in a command prompt  on an Android Genymotion Emulator,but it throws this exception:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

But it was running well before this error why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

goto android folder within your project:

```
cd android
```

then

```
./gradlew clean
```